# Match lines not ending with an specific character

Tags: grep

I have been learning linux commands and got this error. My text is here:

```
Fred apples 20
Susy oranges 12 
Mark watermellons 12
Robert pears 4
Terry oranges 9
Lisa peaches 7
Egemen aaaa 12
Susy oranges 12
Mark grapes 39
Anne mangoes 7
Greg pineapples 3
Oliver rockmellons 2
Betty limes 14
```

I searched for the lines not ending with `2`. My command:

```
egrep '2.+' mysampledata.txt
```

But interestingly I got these two lines:

```
Fred apples 20
Susy oranges 12
```

I tried some other arguments for these command and changed the sequence of the lines. I did not got any false result.

What's wrong with this construction?

Comment: `2.+` does not specify a line ending in `2`. You might instead look to `2$`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want the lines not ending with '2' try the following:

```
grep '[^2]$' <filename>
```

Here '$' matches the end of the line, '[^2] means anything other than '2'. So, '[^2]$' means match any character other than '2' at the end of the line.

Your command `egrep '2.+' mysampledata.txt`, will search for the lines containing '2' and then any character occurring one or more times. So, the output should be:

```
Fred apples 20
```

The additional line `Susy oranges 12` might be due to an `space` wrongly put at the end of the line.

**Edit:** The following will consider any number of whitespaces or any non-printable characters at the end too:

```
grep -v '2[[:blank:][:cntrl:]]*$' <filename>
```

This means print the lines that does not have '2' or '2' followed by any number of whitespaces or control characters at the end of the line.

Answer (score 6):

You should do:

```
grep -v '2 *$' mysampledata.txt
```

The `-v` option reverses the match. This supports lines with spaces at the end, since this is the case on your file and you do not seem to want

```
Susy oranges 12 $
```

to be output (the `$` here marks the end of line).

Comment: @EgemenSarımaden Note that only my answer correctly deals with your problem (supporting spaces at the end of the lines). Add a space after `Betty limes 14` to see the difference.